# Cannot implicitly convert 'bool' to 'int' - collision detection

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I am trying to make a simple collision detection class for a soccer game. Here is the code:

```
int Collision(int x1, int y1, int radius1, int x2, int y2, int radius2)  
{  
    int dx = x2 - x1;  
    int dy = y2 - y1;  
    int radii = radius1 + radius2;  
    if ((dx*dy)+(dy*dy)< radii * radii)  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

The problem is with the code returning true or false. Visual Studio says it cannot implicitly convert bool to int, and I understand that, but how can I fix it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want it to return an int? If so, what value would you like represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your function like this:

```
bool Collision(int x1, int y1, int radius1, int x2, int y2, int radius2)
```

Now you can return `true` or `false`. If you keep `int` then you need to return an integer value such as `0` and `1` but this doesn't express the function intent.

You could also shorten your code a bit:

```
bool Collision(int x1, int y1, int radius1, int x2, int y2, int radius2)  
{  
    int dx = x2 - x1;  
    int dy = y2 - y1;  
    int radii = radius1 + radius2;  
    return ((dx * dy) + (dy * dy) < radii * radii);
}
```

Comment: @NeoHaxxor - simple, yes, but do you understand _why_ it works?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: why you want to change the return type of function , you can use something like this

int result = (dx*dy)+(dy*dy)< radii * radii ? 1:0

and retrun result ;

Comment: @saurab, because when a function has to determine whether two points collide it should return a `boolean` value. It expresses much more clearly its intent to the consumer.

Comment: see my comments , why are you changing the return type , you can use something a<b?1:0  , why are you suggesting to change the return type itself

Comment: @Darin : what about if he uses this function 1000 places

Comment: @saurabh, because it is more appropriate in this case. There's nothing preventing you from using a function that returns a bool value in 1000 places.

Comment: @Darin : can you do something like this 

int i = GetResult() and GetResult is returning true or false without using casting

Comment: @saurabh, no you can't, that's what the OP was trying to do. See the compiler error he is getting.

Comment: i think if you can change something without changing a lot of code , you should prefer that alternative until and otherwise your design is not having some very serious problem.

Comment: so that was my point , changing a return type can break your code a lot of places in this case , so use something which does not break code.

Comment: @saurabh, the code's already broken and there cannot be any consumers of this method simply because this method doesn't even compile. So I really don't understand your point.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to return a true/false variable, you should change your first line to this:

```
bool Collision(int x1, int y1, int radius1, int x2, int y2, int radius2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to fix your algorithm. 
((dx***dy**)+(dy*dy)< radii * radii)
should be:
((dx***dx**)+(dy*dy)< radii * radii)

Just when you think: Whew! I fixed that int/bool thing,, you get a bunch of false positives.