# WPF, How to detect a collision between two Ellipses?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I'm trying to detect a collision between two ellipses

```
public bool CheckCollision(Ellipse a, Ellipse  b)
{     
    if (a.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.IntersectsWith(b.RenderedGeometry.Bounds) )
        return true;
    return false;  
}
```

But it doesnt work because I get true all the  time

Comment: Well, the Ellipse class doesn't store information about the position of the ellipse, so, the boundary rectangles of two ellipses always interesect.

Comment: If the ellipses are actually circles, the collision detection would better be done by subtracting their center Points, which would give you a Vector. You could then check if the Length of the Vector is less than or equal to the sum of the radii of the two circles.

Comment: In order to work with center points, you would replace Ellipse controls by Path controls with an EllipseGeometry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132903/how-to-do-c-sharp-collision-detection