# C# - Search inside for loop

Tags: c#

I'm having troubles with my current code and I wish someone help me to develop a simple one or at least give some ideas (pseudocode).

Basically I have n drones and I want to create a "safe area" around them.

So I want to if drone2 is inside drone1's safe area I want stay outside. **But I want to create for N drones (drone.length)**

**For example:**
If drone2 approaches drone1 from the +x side i want him to stay in position (x+1,y) so they dont collide

[Image of the Safe Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuQnZ.png)

Code:

```
For each Drone I have:
int Xmin
int Xmax 
int Ymin 
int Ymax
string ip (example "192.168.1.10"
Point position (x,y)

for(int i = 0 ; i<drone.length;i++)
{

   //i think I need to check drone's IP to know the current drone being iterated
    If(drone[i].position //is inside every drone[EXCEPT i]’s safe area
              {
                  //debug: Which drone’s safe area is drone[i].position inside?
              }
}
```

Can someone help me please? Thank you so much

Comment: is this actual code or pseudo code?

Comment: Well it's the code I was trying to develop but I got stuck

Comment: FYI this is "Collision Detection". For you it appears you want some sort of 2 dimensional version, possibly for circles but maybe just squares. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540472/collision-detection-implementation) is the first result I came across.

Comment: I know how to see if it's inside. Just check if it's inside xmin,xmax etc... I dont know is the rest.

Comment: How do I check if If(drone[i].position //is inside every drone[EXCEPT i]’s safe area?

Comment: //i think I need to check drone's IP to know the current drone being iterated

Comment: You could go with something like this: `if (drones.Where(d => d.IP != drones[i].IP).Any(d => /*Method to determine if the point is inside d's safezone*/))`

Comment: by method you mean a function? thx

Comment: Hi @Tiago Silva, creating a new user and asking the same question over again isn't going to get you anywhere. You need to break your problem down into smaller questions...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I think I have got this,

For this problem instead of using squares i am going to use Pythagoras theorem which states. `A=sqrt(B^2+C^2)` This will give the distance between each drone.

So in psudocode i would do this:

```
xDangerDrones=[]
yDangerBots=[]
Drones=[] // A list of all your drones
for drone in drones:
 for drone2 in drones:
  if(not (drone==drone2 and check if drone and drone 2 are in lists xDangerDrones and yDangerBots)):
    distance=sqrt(abs(drone.x-drone2.x)^2+abs(drone.y-drone2.y)^2)
    if distance>YOUR RADIUS HERE:
      if (abs(drone.x-drone2.x)>abs(drone.y-drone2.y)):
        if (drone.y>drone2.y)
          yDangerBots.append(drone)
        else:
          yDangerBots.append(drone2)
      else
         if (drone.x>drone2.x)
          xDangerBots.append(drone)
        else:
          xDangerBots.append(drone2)
for xDangerDrone in xDangerDrones:
  drone move right

for yDangerDrone in yDangerDrones:
  drone move up
```

**Edit**

Full Java code as promised:

Drone.java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Asim Poptani on 2/14/2017.
 */
public class Drone {
    private UUID uuid;
    private int positionX;
    private int positionY;

    Drone()
    {
        Random random=new Random();
        uuid= UUID.randomUUID();
        positionX=random.nextInt(100);
        positionY=random.nextInt(100);
    }
    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }



    public int getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public void setPositionX(int positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return positionY;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int positionY) {
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }
}
```

And Main.java

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int emergencyRadius=5;
        HashSet<Drone> moveUp = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Drone> moveDown = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Drone> moveLeft = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Drone> moveRight = new HashSet<>();

        HashSet<Drone> drones= new HashSet<>();
        for (int generator=0;generator<10;generator++)
        {
            drones.add(new Drone());
        }

        for (Drone drone:drones)
        {
            for (Drone drone2:drones){
                if (
                        !(
                                drone==drone2
                                        ||
                                        moveUp.contains(drone)
                                        ||
                                        moveUp.contains(drone2)
                                        ||
                                        moveDown.contains(drone)
                                        ||
                                        moveDown.contains(drone2)
                                        ||
                                        moveLeft.contains(drone)
                                        ||
                                        moveLeft.contains(drone2)
                                        ||
                                        moveRight.contains(drone)
                                        ||
                                        moveRight.contains(drone2)
                        ))
                {
                    double distance=Math.sqrt(Math.abs(drone.getPositionX()-drone2.getPositionX())^2+Math.abs(drone.getPositionY()-drone2.getPositionY())^2);
                    if (distance<emergencyRadius)
                    {
                        if(Math.abs(drone.getPositionX()-drone2.getPositionX())>Math.abs(drone.getPositionY()-drone2.getPositionY()))
                        {
                            if(drone.getPositionY()>drone2.getPositionY())
                            {
                                moveUp.add(drone);
                                moveDown.add(drone2);
                            }
                            else {
                                moveUp.add(drone2);
                                moveDown.add(drone);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if(drone.getPositionX()>drone2.getPositionX())
                            {
                                moveLeft.add(drone);
                                moveRight.add(drone2);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                    moveLeft.add(drone2);
                                    moveRight.add(drone);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (Drone drone:moveUp)
        {
            System.out.print("\nmove up ");
            System.out.print(drone.getUuid());
        }
        for (Drone drone:moveDown)
        {
            System.out.print("\nmove down");
            System.out.print(drone.getUuid());
        }
        for (Drone drone:moveRight)
        {
            System.out.print("\nmove Right ");
            System.out.print(drone.getUuid());
        }
        for (Drone drone:moveLeft)
        {
            System.out.print("\nmove left ");
            System.out.print(drone.getUuid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this code will work with n number of drones. Append means add an element to a list. See here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

Comment: Why do you make the two first for loops?

Comment: This is so we can compare each drone with each other. Essentially think of searching!

Comment: and the last two for? Which drone moves? and what about down and left?

Comment: Currently the program will make the left most drone go left and the top most drone go forward. If you want both drones to evade I.e. go in opposite directions then there is a simple way to do it give me until tomorrow and I will make you some proper Java code for you to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using C# but I think I can understand JAVA. Thanks. I will wait ;)

Comment: @ScumbagSteve Ok give me a few minutes to create the code

Comment: @ScumbagSteve There you go

Comment: Shouldnt it be if (distance<emergencyRadius)?

Comment: You have implemented naive collision detection; this algorithm works for a small number of objects but very quickly runs into difficulties as the number of objects grows large; imagine what happens when you have a thousand or a million possible objects.

Comment: One trick that can make this algorithm faster is: computing square roots is slow, but computing squares is fast.  Instead of computing: `if (root(a*a + b*b) < c)` instead compute `if (a * a + b * b < c * c)`.  It's a lot faster!

Comment: Also, `^` is not the exponentiation operator in Java or C#.

Comment: Also, you don't need to put an `Abs` on a square. Squares are always non-negative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235596/c-sharp-syncronizing-movement-using-queues

Comment: Hi @EricLippert Just a few things this program is meant for avoidance system for a few drones as i understand from the question therefore i have not spent time optimising the program. I agree with your comments and if you wish to you can change my program. Also  what is with the -1?